# Error (status 0) jQuery ajax with Safari and ios 7

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, ipad, safari

I have difficulties to operate an Ajax call with an Ipad (IOS 7.1)
The code below works fine with IE, FF and Chromebut not with Safari (IOS 7.1) installed on Ipad.

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax(
{
    type:'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
    timeout: 5000,
    url:'mydomaine',
    crossDomain:true,
    cache:false,
    async:true,  
    success: function(data) {alert("OK");},
    error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {alert("OK");}
});
```

When calling this code with an iPad (IOS 7.1), I got the following error

```
xhr.status: 0
xhr.statusText: error
xhr.readyState: 0
xhr.responseText: 
xhr.responseXML: undefined
textStatus: error
errorThrown: 
xhr.redirect: undefined
```

I used the following JS libraries

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Note : tNote that the problem occurs with GET and POST type, but not with a PUT.

In addition, the server execute well the http query. For me, the problem is in the treatment of the Response by the Safari browser.

can you help me ?